# Have been 2 weeks since I started learning DOM. Trying to make language switcher. Not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have for the moment two buttons in html:

```
<div>
  <button class="choose-lang" id="eng-btn">English</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="choose-lang" id="rus-btn">Русский</button>
</div>
```

When I click the button of eng-btn, it should switch the class of "eng" to display = "inline" and switch the class of "rus" to display = "none";

```
// My html
<h2 class="form-heading"><span class="eng">Enter your v-number:</span><span class="rus">Введите ваш номер:</span></h2>
```

I kept my CSS file empty, I mean I didn't give any properties to classes of eng and rus in css file.

I wrote in js file the following:

```
var engBtn = document.getElementById("eng-btn");
engBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("eng").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementsByClassName("rus").style.display = "none";
})

var rusBtn = document.getElementById("rus-btn");
rusBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("rus").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementsByClassName("eng").style.display = "none";
})
```

No idea why it is not working

Comment: I can give you a hint :) `document.getElementsByClassName("rus")`  returns a `NodeList` (array) not an actual `HTMLElement`

Comment: @PoulKruijt I wrote in the console console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("eng"));
it returned HTMLcollection

Comment: @PoulKruijt Sorry, just a newbie who has started learning JS and programming in general around 3 months ago. I'm not getting how it is going to help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection and not a single element, and as such id does NOT have DOM element's attributes and methods.

you can try to iterate like so:

```
var engBtn = document.getElementById("eng-btn");
engBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // document.getElementsByClassName("eng").style.display = "inline";
    // document.getElementsByClassName("rus").style.display = "none";

    changeVisibility('rus', 'none');
    changeVisibility('eng', 'inline');
})

var rusBtn = document.getElementById("rus-btn");

rusBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    changeVisibility('rus', 'inline');
    changeVisibility('eng', 'none');
    // document.getElementsByClassName("rus").style.display = "inline";
    // document.getElementsByClassName("eng").style.display = "none";
}); 


function changeVisibility(className, visibility) {
  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(let i = 0 ; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].style.display = visibility;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array which you use an index to access:

e.g.:

`document.getElementsByClassName("eng")[0].style.display = "inline";`

```js
var engBtn = document.getElementById("eng-btn");
engBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("eng")[0].style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementsByClassName("rus")[0].style.display = "none";
})

var rusBtn = document.getElementById("rus-btn");
rusBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("rus")[0].style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementsByClassName("eng")[0].style.display = "none";
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="choose-lang" id="eng-btn">English</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="choose-lang" id="rus-btn">Русский</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="form-heading"><span class="eng">Enter your v-number:</span><span class="rus">Введите ваш номер:</span></h2>
</body>
```

Comment: try to avoid hardcoding an array index whenever possible (e.g. `[0]`). It is better to iterate over the array in case the number of elements changes in the future.

Comment: @Segev-CJ-Shmueli Thank you very much! Good point. I'm learning by your help and many other people